# The App protocol not work with the View's PreviewProvider

Tags: swiftui

The following code can be work in ios13.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

But when I try to use the ios14 feature app protocol, the preview report `require the ContentView confirm to View` error.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ContentView: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            LoginView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is rather naming convention. It is better not name App as View (in this case ContentView)... Xcode use different notation with create from template. Name entry point as something with App and don't use it as View, because it is not view, but App.... like AppDelegate is not UIView, right?

Comment: The ContentView confirm the app protocol and return some Scene, is that mean it can not be preview in xcode 12?

Answer (score 1):

This is because in your new version the `ContentView` is no longer declared as a `View` but as an `App` (I'd suggest to rename it to `ContentApp` to avoid confusion).

And the signature of previews is:

```
static var previews: some View
```

which means it needs to return *some View* (and not *some App*).

---

In your case you probably want to present `LoginView` in previews:

```
struct LoginView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}
```

or if you want to present `ContentView`:

```
@main
struct ContentApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        LoginView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```